# Samson Meteor Mic not working on RPi 3

Tags: audio

My Samson meteor mic isn't working with my Pi 3. It also gives feedback when I plug headphones into it to hear my voice echo. It also works with my iMac.
I am trying to run JasperPi (jasperproject.github.io).

```
OS: Raspbian
System: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
Project: Jasper Pi
```

Thanks for any help. :)

Edit: The mic also makes noise when a key is held down/clicked

Comment: A url to the mic would help, and how do you connect it?